# Automating a Report: Selecting from a drop down in IE using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to automate a report of mine using VBA. I was able to do the log in part and all but when it comes to navigating the next webpage with drop downs I can't seem to get a hold of it. I tried multiple ways to fill out the first drop down which is the report type and I can't find the correct code

All commented  "'" are all the codes I've tried. I can't post the website since it's a client website.

[html "inspect elemet" photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nwoL.png)

```
Sub Get_RawFile()

 Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
 Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
 Dim addressInput As HTMLInputElement

 With IE
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate ("------------------------")

    While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

    Set HTMLDoc = IE.document
    HTMLDoc.all.UserName.Value = Sheets("Data Dump").Range("A1").Value
    HTMLDoc.all.Password.Value = Sheets("Data Dump").Range("B1").Value
    HTMLDoc.getElementById("login-btn").Click

    While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

    'HTMLDoc.getElementByName("ddlReportType")(0).Value = "1"

    'Set HTMLDoc = IE.document
    'Set evtChange = HTMLDoc.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
    'evtChange.initEvent "change", True, False
    'Set selectElement = HTMLDoc.getElementById("ddlReportType")
    'selectElement.Value = "1" 'Attendance
    'selectElement.dispatchEvent evtChange
    'Set htmlSelectElem = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("ddlReportType")
    'htmlSelectElem.selectedIndex = 1

    'Set reporttype = IE.document.getElementById("ddlReportType")

    'For i = 1 To reporttype.Options.Length
     'If reporttype.Options(i).Text = "Attendance" Then
      'reporttype.selectedIndex = i
      'Exit For
    'End If
   'Next i

 End With
```

> Run-time error '438'
>   Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: Please share the `HTML` part of web page drop down you are trying to change value

Comment: Hi @arunv! Below is the link for the image file of the html part of the web page.

https://scontent.fyxd2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/67483360_10217670489866939_1603503839275646976_n.jpg?_nc_cat=101&_nc_oc=AQlL1b8-4SREL-Qfo1YFHNvdgWG-dMKNkxgaaSrlNeO5uqD3HVOElq7z8mbw_chCtq8&_nc_ht=scontent.fyxd2-1.fna&oh=4907acd02831f4932d57fb3fa417d6d4&oe=5DE46BDD

Answer (score 0):

This method `.getElementByName` does not exist. It should be `.getElementsByName("Something")`, in which case the method returns a collection of elements whose `Name` attribute is `Something`.

The following would access the first element of the collection of elements whose `Name` attribute is `ddlReportType` and set its value to `1`:

```
HTMLDoc.getElementsByName("ddlReportType")(0).Value = "1"
```

Having said that, you don't seem so sure as to what `ddlReportType` is.

If it's the `id` of an element then the element should look like so:

```
<tagName id="ddlReportType">Something</tagName>
```

In that case you should use the method `.getElementByID()`

If it's the `Name` of an element then the element should look like so:

```
<tagName Name="ddlReportType">Something</tagName>
```

In that case you should use the method `.getElementsByName()`, which returns a collection of elements.

If it's the `Class` of an element then the element should look like so:

```
<tagName Class="ddlReportType">Something</tagName>
```

In that case you should use the method `.getElementsByClassName()`, which returns a collection of elements.

Finally, I can tell you for sure that **it's not** a `Tag Name` so you definitely **shouldn't** use the `.getElementsByTagName` method.

**EDIT**

From the image you provided after editing your original post, it is clear that `ddlReportType` is the `id` of a `<select></select>` element. So you should do it this way:

```
Dim HTMLselect As HTMLSelectElement
Set HTMLselect = HTMLDoc.getElementById("ddlReportType")
HTMLselect.Value = "1"
```

References used: `Microsoft HTML Object Library` (VBE>Tools>References>...)

That's how to select one of the drop down options. To navigate further you would have to press some button I presume.

Comment: Hello I appreciate this. I have updated by question with the image of the inspect element. I also have tried `HTMLDoc.getElementsByName` code but I wasn't able to get the value. Thanks!

Comment: @Hervie I edited my answer accordingly. See if that's what you need.

Comment: Hello again! I think it worked a little bit? When I run the macro it doesn't give me any error message but when I check the dropdown it doesn't show the "Attendance" which is `HTMLselectReport.Value = "1"` as selected. It's just highlighted when I click on the drop down but it isn't really selected. Can you walk me through further?

Comment: @Hervie try `HTMLselect.Options(1).Selected = True`

Comment: Hi @stavros. I get the same results. It just highlights the "Attendance"

Comment: @Hervie when you do it manually what do you do? Do you press a button after selecting the option? Does the next page load automatically?

Comment: After the log-in page, I just select the report type manually via drop down and set the date ranges then there's just an run report and export button.